# Using would to express the simple future

Tags: grammar, would

Is the follow grammatically correct:

*He reserved the sleeper.  It **would** leave just before midnight so he wouldn't need to leave home till half past nine.*

The 'would' seems to express the future and there is little doubt the train will leave.  If anyone could tell me what part of grammar the 'would' represents I'd appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: What is a sleeper?

Comment: Leaky Nun it is an over night train where you get a bed.

Comment: "Would" is also the past tense of "will". The whole passage is in the past.

Comment: Many tx msam.  I missed the obvious.  Duh

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The *would* (twice) expresses the so-called future in the past (talking about the future from the point of view of the past). One could also write, and this might be more colloquial: *He reserved the sleeper. It was going to leave just before midnight so he wouldn't need to leave home till half past nine.* Either way, it's future in the past.

Comment: tx clare.  Much appreciated